# Page fails to render but no error message

Tags: blazor

VS 2017 build 15.9.3
Blazor runtime 0.7 rtm 
Trying my hand at Blazor.  Have a simple page that I am trying to get a Dropdown to fill with items from a list of objects.  Project builds, but the page does not render nor any errors or exceptions generated. Other pages work fine, just not this one.  It's obviously something with the select since if I remove that, it renders fine.  However, I see no errors - either in the browser or in visual studio.  I'm launching from VS with F5 so I can debug if needed.

```
@page "/PriceList"


<p>Audit screen test</p>

<select id="selPriceRate" bind="@prices">
    <option value="test">test</option>
</select>

<br/>
Select terminal:<br/>
<select id="ddTerminal" onchange="@ChangeTerminal" >
    <option value="NYC">NYC</option>
    <option value="LHR">LHR</option>
    <option value="DFW">DFW</option>
    <option value="LAX">LAX</option>
</select>

@functions {

    List<PriceSetting> prices = new List<PriceSetting>();

    void ChangeTerminal()
    {
        // load ddRateMaster
        prices.Add(new PriceSetting() { PriceName = "test1",PriceValue = 104.13m });
        prices.Add(new PriceSetting() { PriceName = "test2", PriceValue = 105.13m });
        prices.Add(new PriceSetting() { PriceName = "test3", PriceValue = 106.13m });
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        var t = prices.Count();

        await Task.Delay(1000);

    }

}
```

Comment: Also no error in de browser console window?

Comment: Correct, nothing in the browser dev console (chrome).  Im using server-side hosting model

Comment: And the correct version of the .net core SDK installed?

Comment: Two projects - (1) Todo.Server - .Net Core 2.1, (2) Todo.App - .Net Standard 2.0

Comment: Not what I mean. what does `dotnet --list-sdks` say? 2.1.500 should be in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the supposition that you want to create two select elements; one 
to display list of airports, and the second a list of prices. (This is the best I could make out of your question )
Now, when the user select an airport, you want the second select to list the prices, right ?

```
@if (Terminals == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <select bind="@SelectedTerminalId">
        <option value=@(0)></option>
        @foreach (var Terminal in Terminals)
        {
            <option value="@Terminal.TerminalId">@Terminal.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
}

@if (SelectedTerminalId != default)
{
    var prices = Terminal.Single(x => x.TerminalId == SelectedTerminalId).Prices;

    <select bind="@SelectedPriceSettingId">
        <option value=@(0)></option>
        @foreach (var price in Prices)
        {
            <option value="@price.Id">@price.Name (@price.Value)</option>
        }
    </select>

}

@functions {
    private static readonly List<Terminal> Terminals = new List<Terminal>{
            new Terminal{
                TerminalId = 1, Name = "NYC", Prices = new List<PriceSetting>
                {
                    new PriceSetting{Id = 1, Name = "test1", Value = 104.13m},
                    new PriceSetting{Id = 2, Name = "test2", Value = 105.13m )
                }
            },
            new Terminal{
                TerminalId = 2, Name = "LHR", Prices = new List<PriceSetting>
                {
                    new PriceSetting{Id = 3, Name = "test3", Value = 106.13m}

                }
            }
        };


    int _selectedTerminalId;
    int SelectedTerminalId
    {
        get => _selectedTerminalId;
        set
        {
            _selectedTerminalId = value;
            SelectedPriceSettingId = default;
        }
    }

    int SelectedPriceSettingId { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Good answer and more detailed than my. It has some typos, i fixed it and created example based on your code https://blazorfiddle.com/s/t4xj7n5l

Answer (score 1):

You just tried to bind prices list

```
List<PriceSetting> prices = new List<PriceSetting>();
```

to select element value.

```
<select id="selPriceRate" bind="@prices">
<option value="test">test</option>
</select>
```

That is not correct.
You can try something like this

```
<select id="selPriceRate" bind="@selectedPriceName">
@foreach(var price in prices) {
    <option value="@price.PriceName">@price.PriceName</option>
}    
</select>
```

or

```
<select id="selPriceRate" onchange="@ChangePriceRate">
@foreach(var price in prices) {
    <option value="@price.PriceName">@price.PriceName</option>
}    
</select>
```

Note: You can not use bind and onchange at same element
[@bind and @onchange on the same element doesn't work](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/524)